# How to remove extra div height when using flex auto for content with dynamic/unknown height of header, content and footer section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a modal of dynamic height with top margin of 32px and height to fit content in the modal but also expands upto bottom with minimum bottom margin of 32px if the content is too much and when that happens a scrollbar comes in the content section. The header, content and footer are of dynamic or unknown height. I have used flex for managing height of modal according to its content height. The problem I am facing is that the height of modal is expanding to bottom of screen even though the content is less. I don't want it expand to bottom if the content is less. Can someone please help me with it ?

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/gm3f16h0/12/

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="header">
        Some header content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        Some footer content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS - 
.overlay {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
   background: black
}

.modal {
   background: white;
   position: relative;
   padding: 2rem;
   width: 46rem;
   margin: 2rem auto;
   box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   border-radius: 4px;
   height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .header {
    background: red;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
 }

 .content {
    background: green;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }

 .footer {
    background: blue;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `flex: 1 1 auto;` to `0 1 auto` from your `.content` and  your problem should be solved.
With the first 0, you change the flex-grow value.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: black
}

.modal {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 46rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="header">
        Some header content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
           
        Some body content <br />
        Some body content <br />
    
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        Some footer content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's better visible here https://jsfiddle.net/3Lq4c82x/, if you don't open the example above full screen.

Comment: Yeah, it fixes the problem of flex-grow but the modal's height is still elongated. I want it to fit with content too.